# Split string from a preset list of strings from pandas df column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like below. It has about a million rows.

```
name = ['Jake','Matt', 'Henry']

0   A        
1 Jake Hill
2 Matt Dawn
3 Matt King
4 White Henry
5 Hyde Jake
```

I want to iterate over the list and the df['A'] column and return only the first names. For example, the final dataframe should look like this.

```
0   A
1  Jake
2  Matt
3  Matt
4  Henry
5  Jake
```

Thanks in advance. I am new to python so still figuring out the easiest way to do this.

Comment: what if value of column A doesn't exist in list?

Comment: What about first names that aren't Jake,Matt,Henry ? Do you want to filter them out?

Comment: Then the original name should be retained. For example if the name is Dave Atkins then it should retain the name Dave Atkins but I have made sure that I have all the names. So that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
first_name = ['Jake','Matt', 'Henry']

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Jake Hill', 'Matt Dawn', 'Matt King', 'Henry White','Jake Hyde','Dwayne John']})

def func(x):
    for k in first_name:
        if k in x:
            return k 
    return x

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Output:

```
            A
0           Jake
1           Matt
2           Matt
3          Henry
4           Jake
5    Dwayne John
```

Comment: Hey. This specifically takes the first string after the split but it does not work if you have to extract a specific string from the column rows. I edited the question a little bit. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of names to match, and a Series of names to check against.  Use a regular expression with `str.extract` here.

```
df.A.str.extract(r'({})'.format('|'.join(name)))
```

```
       0
0   Jake
1   Matt
2   Matt
3  Henry
4   Jake
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method to achieve this:

```
first_name = ['Jake','Matt', 'Henry']

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Jake Hill', 'Matt Dawn', 'Matt King', 'Henry White', 'Jake Hyde']})

df['B'] = df['A'].str.split().apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[0] in first_name else ' '.join(x))
```

and you get:

```
             A      B
0    Jake Hill   Jake
1    Matt Dawn   Matt
2    Matt King   Matt
3  Henry White  Henry
4    Jake Hyde   Jake
```

Comment: Hey Gerges. This specifically takes the first string after the split but it does not work if you have to extract a specific string from the column rows. I edited the question a little bit. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = ['Jake','Matt', 'Henry']
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

#filling nan values in-case if it is there
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df["First Name"] = df.A.apply(lambda x: list(set(x.split(" ")) & set(name))[0]  if x != 0 else "Not Found")
```

Output:

```
             A First Name
0    Jake Hill       Jake
1    Matt Dawn       Matt
2    Matt King       Matt
3  Henry White      Henry
4    Hyde Jake       Jake
```

Comment: Hey Chirag. This specifically takes the first string after the split but it does not work if you have to extract a specific string from the column rows. I edited the question a little bit. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In  addition to earlier edit, Which i understood now you want to inplace replacement, Which can be done with list comprehension as follows with splitting the column `A` Fist and choose the First Index of of it and passing to lambda using `apply` method.

**DataFrame Structure:**

```
df
             A
0    Jake Hill
1    Matt Dawn
2    Matt King
3  Henry White
4    Jake Hyde
```

**Your `name` Var..**

```
$ name
['Jake', 'Matt', 'Henry']
```

**Your Final desired Dataset:**

Parameter n can be used to limit the number of splits in the output.

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)[0].apply(lambda x: x if x in name else ' '.join(x))

   print(df)
           A
    0   Jake
    1   Matt
    2   Matt
    3  Henry
    4   Jake
```

---

It should be simple if you not pressed to take names from a Var and end goal is to get the First name from the dataframe  :

```
>>> df
             A
0    Jake Hill
1    Matt Dawn
2    Matt King
3  Henry White
4    Jake Hyde


>>> df['A'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)[0]
0     Jake
1     Matt
2     Matt
3    Henry
4     Jake
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

OR In case you want inplace replacement for column `A` ..

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)[0]
```

Comment: your input df is different from the user input.  In this problem first name is customised.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah, thnx for the feedback but did not get you, but intent is same.

Comment: In your input df at 3 rd index, user provides as `White Henry` but you took it as `Henry White`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`A_final=A[0].str.split(' ',expand=True, n=1).str.get(0)
 A_final[0]`
, your problem is resolved.

Comment: What is this doing?

Answer (score 0):

This method won't be fooled by a last name containing one of the first name strings, such as "Matten" or "Jakes", and will combine a first and last name if they are both found in the first names list, such as "Matt Henry" (shows "MattHenry" in the output dataframe).

```
# split the name strings into columns as new dataframe
df1 = df.A.str.split(' ', expand=True)
# Keep the first names in the new dataframe and fill the rest with
# empty strings, then sum the df1 column string values to make a new array
names_result = np.where(df1.isin(name), df1, '').sum(axis=1)
# find the array indexes where no first names were found
no_match_idx = np.where(names_result == '')[0]
# fill the no first name index locations with original dataframe values
names_result[no_match_idx] = df.A.values[no_match_idx]
# make a dataframe using the results
df_out = pd.DataFrame(names_result, columns=['A'])

# to find names with a first and last name that are both found in the
# first names list:
# df_out['dups'] = df1.isin(name).sum(axis=1) > 1
```